# Error when fitting Bayesian model with the Rethinking R package

Tags: r, syntax-error, bayesian, model-fitting

I'm trying to fit a very simple model to estimate the prevalence of disease as described here https://www.ecdc.europa.eu/sites/default/files/documents/Methodology-estimating-point-prevalence%20-SARS-CoV-2-infection-pooled-RT-PCR-testing.pdf on page 6, using the Rethinking R package

Here's my code:

```
quap(alist(
    p ~ dbeta(.3, .3),
    p_test ~ 1 - dbinom(0, s, p), # I tried also p_test <- 1 - dbinom(0, s, p)
    k ~ dbinom(w, p_test)
), data = list(s = 10, k = 30, w = 200))
```

but I receive the error:
`Error in pars[[i]] : subscript out of bounds in quap`

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Consists your data of a single observation? I never used the `rethinking` package but in most samplers (rjags, rstan, etc) we would expect a list of lists or vectors here...

Comment: Yep is count data. it shouldn't be a problem I believe. A Stan version of the same model doesn't complain at least.

Comment: ok. never mind then ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reordering of definitions in `alist` does the trick.

```
quap(
 alist(
    k ~ dbinom(w, p_test),
    p ~ dbeta(.3, .3),
    p_test ~ 1 - dbinom(0, s, p) 
 ), 
 data = list(s = 10, k = 30, w = 200)
)
```

This code returns:

```
Quadratic approximate posterior distribution

Formula:
k ~ dbinom(w, p_test)
p ~ dbeta(0.3, 0.3)
p_test ~ 1 - dbinom(0, s, p)

Posterior means:
         p 
0.01575975 

Log-likelihood: -2.55
```

Comment: Thank you! do you have any idea why?

Comment: I don't know exactly why as I haven't checked the code of `quap`. I have always followed the structure of likelihood followed by priors as it is vaguely written in help of `quap` (flist should be a either a single formula that defines the likelihood function or rather a list of formulas that define the likelihood and priors for parameters. See examples below.)